# Recoger los datos de medición de campañas de Google Play con Ionic + Angular + Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic, ng-cordova, google-analytics

Estoy intentado recoger los datos de **medición de campañas de Google Play** en mi aplicación (AngularJS + Ionic + Cordova) creando una *URL* a través de [esta herramienta de **Google Analytics**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder)

Genero una *URL* parecida a esta:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.name&referrer=utm_source%3DTest

En **Cordova**, tengo añadidos estos dos plugins para recoger los datos:

> [android-referrer-plugin](https://github.com/8zrealestate/android-referrer-plugin)
>
> [cordova-plugin-app-preferences](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences)

En **AngularJS** he añadido `ngCordova` como modulo y en la función de "*run*" la he configurado para recoger los datos:

```
app.run(function( ..., $cordovaPreferences) {

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

            $cordovaPreferences.fetch('referrer')
              .success(function(value) {

                    alert("Success: " + value);
                    // Guardar en localStorage
                    window.localStorage.setItem("cookies", value);
              });

     }, false);
});
```

Cuando ejecuto [el comando para testear si recibo los datos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890914/how-to-test-android-referral-tracking) los recibo correctamente (se muestran en el alert y los puedo recoger en cualquier momento del *localStorage*).

**Cuando subo la app a Google Play no recibo ningún dato y me llega siempre vacío. ¿Alguien sabe porque puede estar pasando?**

*Ayuda:*

Cuando muestro la variable `$cordovaPreferences` me aparece este mensaje dentro del objecto, pero continúa funcionando (ejecutando `ionic build android`):

[image: Objecto $cordovaPreferences]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Cuando instalo la aplicación que está subida en la `Google Play` y miro los logs del dispositivo (con la herramienta `logcat`) me aparecen estas lineas:

> 05-03 17:50:20.928  2413  2430 D GAv4    : Received installation
>   campaign: content=test_content, keyword=test_term, medium=test_medium,
>   name=test_name, source=test_source
>
> 05-03 17:51:17.888  2413  2430 D GAv4    : Found relevant installation
>   campaign: content=test_content, keyword=test_term, medium=test_medium,
>   name=test_name, source=test_source

En cambio, cuando la instalo en local y ejecuto el comando para simular la llamada de **Google Play** no me aparecen esos mensajes pero si me llegan los datos a la aplicación.

Dejo aquí el comando para simular la llamada de **Google Play**:

```
echo 'am broadcast \
    -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER \
    -n "com.framework.appName/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver" \
    --es "referrer" \
      "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name"; \
    exit' | adb shell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución pasa por añadir este plugin a **Cordova**:

[cordova-plugin-google-analytics](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin)

y todo funciona correctamente.